# Android: uncecking the check box on button click

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement clearing all the check marks of check boxes on single button click, code seems okay for me but it isn't working. Checkboxes is in different layout...in my present activity I'm inflating the checkboxes and  doing setChecked(false)(which is not working)..is there any another way?

```
Button clearbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
        clearbtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {



                LayoutInflater inflater_example = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                View v1= inflater_example.inflate(R.layout.profile, null); 
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                checkBox.setChecked(false); 
        }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: inflating the layout will not work.. you are not setting this inflated view to your layout anywhere.. so the change won't reflect. Where is the checkbox in ? your parent layout?

Comment: parent layout is different and check box is in different layou..can u suggets what to do

Comment: checkbox is displayed in the same activity ?

Comment: yes checkbox is displayed in same activity

Comment: @teekib improve your question its difficult to answer due lack of information.

Comment: profile activity layout has has clear button..in another layout i have checkbox..i am inflating in adapter the checkbox and calling the adapter in activity.

Comment: @teekib post the entire code which is related to your checkbox.

Comment: here is my activity http://pastebin.com/WuAHYsky

Comment: what adapter? if the `CheckBox` in the same `Activity`, why isn't it in the same layout? if you answer that, maybe we can offer more conventional methods to solve the problem

Comment: @Robinhood  here is my adapter http://pastebin.com/AZqFYw9A

Comment: have u use LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: yes i used that but not working

Comment: @mango  please looa at the linkd my activity and adapter   pastebin.com/WuAHYsky     ..    pastebin.com/AZqFYw9A

Comment: have u use LayoutInflater controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

Comment: i've looked at them, but it doesn't help me help you. why isn't this `CheckBox` in the same layout that your activity is using? Are you intending to *add* a `CheckBox` to aforementioned layout and set it to `false`? what purpose does your adapter play in relation to this specific question?

Comment: that adapter inflates the profile.xml which has the checkbox and other views i am retreiving the phone contacts..

Comment: @DixitPatel i tried that LayoutInflater controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);..not working

Comment: have you use inflated layout in your activity

Comment: i already have diff layout for activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your adapter has these views that you want to effect. standard OOP principles dictate that you make *adapter* methods to go about it. judging from your adapter technique and how it deftly combats `convertView` to persist checkbox states, i'd think the method would be self-evident. simply set the `boolean` flags that determine their states and refresh the adapter. here's a sample adapter method, that you can call from the button's `OnClickListener`

```
private void clearChecks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.checkBoxState.length; i++) {
        Constants.checkBoxState[i] = false;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: exactly .. implemented the same thing as below..thanks a ton  private boolean selectStatus() {
  boolean result = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < Constants.checkBoxState.length; i++) {
   if (Constants.checkBoxState[i] == true) {
    return false;
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

}

Answer (score 1):

Just clear all the checkbox states in Constants and notify or reset adapter for the change to reflect.

```
Button clearbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
    clearbtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
          for(int i=0;i < Constants.checkBoxState.length; i++)      
             Constants.checkBoxState[i] = false;

          listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    });
```